# insert collection when inserting row mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

simply i want when insert in table employee insert collection of phone numbers for each employee.
i know how to do this in UI (client side java script) i need a specific code (when i increase number of phone in client side increase size of objects from type phone

i read this :

http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html

every thing is fine but when i increase the number of phone in UI more than two only insert 2 row in database because of this : my entry point

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var Employee = new employee();
    Employee.CreatePhoneNumbers(2);
    return View(Employee);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(employee emp) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        telephoneEntities db = new telephoneEntities();
        foreach(phon phone in emp.phons.ToList()) {
            if (phone.deletephon == true) {
                emp.phons.Remove(phone);
            }
        }
        db.employees.Add(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View();
}
```

i need javascript to change this value 2 or 3 ....(the number of phone added in UI)

thank

Comment: You will need to include the `[HttpPost]` method of the controller that is actually saving to the database. the `CreatePhoneNumbers` method may be useful as well.

Comment: i have one         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(employee emp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                telephoneEntities db = new telephoneEntities();
                foreach (phon phone in emp.phons.ToList())
                {
                    if (phone.deletephon == true)
                    {
                        emp.phons.Remove(phone);
                    }
                }
                
   db.employees.Add(emp);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
            return View();
    }

Comment: You should UPDATE your original question with this code so that people can read it. Putting it in comments for cannot format it properly. I would provide us with the HTML your solution is producing when you try and add more than 2 phone numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to.

```
Employee.CreatePhoneNumbers(2);
```

The above line is just setting the starting amount of phone number boxes when the view is rendered for the first time. If you then add more phone number fields in the UI and save the record it will all be taken care of.

Have you stepped into the code to see if there are more than 2 phone numbers in the model being passed into the New method?

Have you read and completed part 2 and 3 of the tutorial??

Comment: yes i stepped just pass 2 the number in parameter i read till part 2 in the article

Comment: Have you compared the HTML your solution produces with that of the tutorial to make sure that it matches the correct pattern? http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ywHaFkp4W4A/UWjo-72LGOI/AAAAAAAAEIE/IF6NxZjEb_c/s1600/8.png

Comment: yes and its work only in delete i can manage when user remove phone but i can't increase the number of phone objects

Comment: matt you are right just wrong bind in html parameter in
@Html.AddLink("Add More Phone Numbers", "#phoneNumbers", ".phoneNumber", "phons", typeof(nestedcolection.Models.phon))

pass the fourth parameter  Phone Which the name of the class not the name of the collection